# Face masking for texture paint in UV / Image Editor

Tags: texture-painting, masking

There is "Face selection masking for painting" while in Texture painting in 3D View,
but I want to paint with a texture brush in the *UV / Image Editor*, so that the texture is not view angle dependent.

Is it possible to paint only on the area of specific faces, while in UV / Image Editor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really at the moment.

Masks are not supported yet in the image editor though it is a feature that we will surely be implementing in the future.

Comment: well, that's disappointing but at least now i know not to look any further and go with the external application approach suggested [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6350/uv-painting-within-blender)