# How can I get the fill and mask options?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I have seen other people having more options in the Image paint tool menu, 
just like the picture below.

[image: Brush settings]

I only have the options draw, soften, smear and clone while he also has fill and mask options.

---

I found out what was wrong after some experiments. It turned out that when i turned on 3D view: Screencast key it made me unable to use the paint tools.

Comment: Welcome to the site :) Please try and keep to one question per post (but feel free to make as many posts as you like). This helps keep posts cleaner and focused on one subject, which will help others looking for answers to the same question. That said, here's a related post: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6350/599

Answer (score 5):

Make sure, that you have the same **Blender Version** used in the tutorial. Most of them announce which version they use.
The Fill Tool is not available in the 2.71 Version. This is a development of the Google Summer of code 2013 and it's planned to merge this tools in the 2.72 Version.

Currently you can download a build from http://graphicall.org/. (seach for "Paint")

For examle http://graphicall.org/1107 (tested, works)

---

If you want to draw a **Line** you can change the Stroke Stettings:
[image: Stroke Method: Line]

Comment: thank you very much, it was just what I where looking for :)

Comment: Even if they don't announce the version they use, it's almost always visible next to the blender logo at the top of the screen (in the info header) @kakan If this answers your question, feel free to mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark under to the voting icons :)